# Collection of APX-hard problems

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Everyone knows "Garey & Johnson", which is my go-to reference whenever I need a problem to transform from for an NP-hardness proof. However I recently find myself in need of an APX-hardness proof, and I wonder if there is a similar (and more up to date..?) collection of problems that have been shown to be APX-hard.

Does anybody know of anything like this? I find it hard to believe that there is no website systematically collecting such problems, but my Google skills seem to be insufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [this compendium](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/problemlist/compendium.html) a few times...
Is this what you were aiming for?

Comment: That is already very nice, thank you! However, the optimum would be something even more comprehensive, and searchable for APX-hardness... I'll see if anything else pops up.

Comment: Can you provide any citation information that will help find this information if the link stops working?  We want answers to remain useful even if the link stops working (and we'd prefer not to be just a link farm).

Comment: It looks like this collection is part of a book, namely:

Ausiello, Giorgio, et al. Complexity and approximation: Combinatorial optimization problems and their approximability properties. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540654315
DOI: 10.1007/978-3-642-58412-1